# Travis CI: Sporadic timeouts to localhost

Tags: travis-ci

The Dropwizard build fails sporadically on a network timeout to localhost. The test spins up a jetty web server on whatever free port is available. Then the test creates a client and makes a request, it uses the same free port picked. That request is what times out on travis-ci. We are not able to repro running locally, but happens with reasonable frequency on travis. Example failure below.

https://travis-ci.org/dropwizard/dropwizard/builds/76668866

Comment: Same problem with my project and Wiremock : https://travis-ci.org/davinkevin/Podcast-Server